# Is subquery the solution to this?

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

Here's the table structure and some sample data:

```
pID.....month.....year

27 .....3    .....2008

27 .....12   .....2012

31 .....6    .....2008

99 .....1    .....2006

42 .....1    .....2009
```

pID is the practiceID and month and year represent the date period they've entered data for. I need to grab the number of practices that have entered data for the first time in Oct 2012, Nov 2012, Dec 2012 and so on. 
I tried the following query for Oct 2012:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    IPIPKDIS
where
    practiceID NOT IN (
         SELECT practiceID
         from
             IPIPKDIS
         where
             year < 2012 and month < 10
    )
    and year = 2012
    and month = 10
    and measureCatRecID = 2
ORDER BY year, month;
```

but it's grabbing months and year less than 10/2012.

If I run the queries isolated (not as subquery) they both work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: please explain "entered data for the first time in Oct 2012"

Comment: if you remove that subquery , how is the result?

Answer (score 0):

This summary query will yield the first (smallest) date in the table for each value of practiceID.

```
SELECT practiceID,
       MIN(STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(year, ' ', month), '%Y %m')) first_date 
  FROM IPIPKDIS 
 GROUP BY practiceID
```

If you want to retrieve then the whole row for the first reported month, you'd do a nested query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM IPIPKDIS I
  JOIN (
    SELECT practiceID,
           MIN(STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(year, ' ', month), '%Y %m')) first_date 
      FROM IPIPKDIS 
     GROUP BY practiceID
       ) first ON (    first.practiceID = I.practiceID 
               AND STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(I.year, ' ', I.month), '%Y %m') = first.first_date)
```

The trick to the second query is to use the JOIN to extract just the first-month rows from your table.  We use date arithmetic to do the date comparisons.